# Download mp3 instead of playing with Webkit

Tags: android

I am using Android 1.5

I am trying to download mp3 via URL link, but instead of download proccess I get auto-play via the webkit.
I do want to download the mp3 file, not to play it straightly from the browser.

Any idea how could I solve this?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send an HTTP [`Content-Disposition`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-170) header, like this:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="file.mp3"
```

You can also set the MIME type to `application/force-download`, but that shouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: I havnt done it inside an application, i am just clicking mp3 link and willing to have it downloaded then being played.

Comment: @rayman Sorry, stackoverflow is for programmers only. Don't worry though, our sister site superuser.com is basically the same thing, just for users.

Comment: I am a programmer, but you right, the question is not in the place. thanks.